# Setting up Khan academy development environment in windows having issue while cloning public source repository

Tags: mercurial, repository, clone, development-environment, kiln

I used TortoiseHG source control tool to clone the public repository of Khan academy [website](http://khanacademy.org)  from https://khanacademy.kilnhg.com/Code/Website/Group/stable using the following command
`hg clone https://khanacademy.kilnhg.com/Code/Website/Group/stable`
But I get an error "stream ended unexpectedly" in the middle of cloning process.

Here is my question. 
How to get exact khan academy website working in my local machine win7 (I have installed Python, Google app engine, gdata python client and all the infra-structure needed) as this source repository is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Note that this article mentions this clone address:

```
hg clone https://khanacademy.kilnhg.com/Repo/Website/Group/stable
# instead of:
#  clone https://khanacademy.kilnhg.com/Code/Website/Group/stable
```

which differs from the one you used.
You will find a similar address in this [`setup.py` `get_khanacademy_code()` function](https://khanacademy.kilnhg.com/Code/Website/Group/stable/File/offline/setup.py?rev=tip#71)

---

In your case, I would rather expect some kind of issue with the [May 6 FogBugz On Demand Upgrade and Network Maintenance](http://status.fogcreek.com/2012/05/fogbugz-on-demand-upgrade-and-network-maintenance-sunday-may-6-0200-utc.html).

Comment: thanks for the timely reply.
[link](https://khanacademy.kilnhg.com/Code/Website/Group/stable/File/offline/setup.py?rev=tip#81) says that the python script uses the same

"hg clone https://khanacademy.kilnhg.com/Repo/Website/Group/stable" 
to clone the website. But I changed the URL as you said. The error is gone :)  It may look silly doubt but i don't have an option.
 All the files have .i extension and repository does not have original file extensions like .js , .html, .py. Does that mean original files are not cloned and only the metadata is cloned?

Comment: @Sathish I just tested and Repo/ actually redirect to Code/, so the actual code should still be in the address you were using initially. So maybe the status of Kiln might explain why the repo url isn't available? (http://status.fogcreek.com/)